# If $f$ is a Morse function, then so is $f \circ \phi^{-1}$, where $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is the coordinate chart.

Tags: calculus, differential-topology

I am trying to show: if when $f^\prime = 0$, then $f^{\prime\prime} \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow (f \circ \phi^{-1})^\prime = 0$, $(f \circ \phi^{-1})^{\prime\prime} \neq 0$.

But the problem is, because $(f \circ \phi^{-1})^\prime = f^\prime(\phi(x))\phi^\prime(x)$, when $(f \circ \phi^{-1})^\prime = 0$, it could be $f^\prime = 0$ or $\phi^\prime = 0$. Can I simply regard $\phi$ as a change of coordinate function hence its Jacobian is nonsingular, so $\phi^\prime \neq 0$?

$(f \circ \phi^{-1})^{\prime\prime} 
= (f^\prime(\phi(x))\phi^\prime(x))^\prime
= f^{\prime\prime}(\phi(x))\phi^\prime(x)\phi^\prime(x) + f^\prime(\phi(x))\phi^{\prime\prime}(x)$

Assuming $f^\prime(\phi(x))=0, \phi^\prime \neq 0$:
$(f \circ \phi^{-1})^{\prime\prime} = f^{\prime\prime}(\phi(x))\phi^\prime(x)\phi^\prime(x) \neq 0$

Assuming $\phi^\prime = 0:
(f \circ \phi^{-1})^{\prime\prime}  = 0$ Failed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If $\phi$ is a coordinate chart, then $\phi$ is bijective.  So, yes, $\phi' \neq 0$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Exactly, thank you Jesse! And I believe my "devrivatire matrix $\phi^\prime(u)$ has maximal rank $k$ is equivalent to your bijective.

Comment: Not quite. $\phi$ bijective $\implies$ $\phi'(u)$ has maximal rank $k$, but not conversely. I think you mean that: $\phi'(u)$ has maximal rank $k$ $\iff$ Derivative matrix $\phi'$ is invertible $\iff$ Derivative matrix $\phi'$ is bijective.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Yeah, exactly. I was wrong. Thank you so much for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a calculus question. The given condition "coordinate chart" is strong. I found this in my calculus book: *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables*, Edwards

Definition: Let $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $\mathscr{C}^1$ mapping defined on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^k (k \leq n)$. Then we call $\phi$ *regular* if the devrivatire matrix $\phi^\prime(u)$ has maximal rank $k$, for each $u \in U$.

Definition: Given $p \in M$, there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k (k<n)$ and a regular $\mathscr{C}^1$ mapping $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $p \in \phi(U)$, with $\phi(U^\prime)$ being an open subset of $M$ for each open set $U^\prime \subset U$. Then the mapping $\phi$ is called a coordinate patch for $M$ provided it is injective.

Certainly, a full rank matrix can't be an empty matrix.